# Pinescript alert for strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am having  a problem in tradingview, pinescript.

I am stuck at a point, I have converted my strategy into study for alerts. Buy and Sell alerts are converted into alerts but the main problem is, I cannot convert `strategy.exit` code in study with alert condition. Is there a way I can convert this also in alert?

Below is my code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28)), comment="Buy")
strategy.exit("Buy", trail_points=100, loss=100, comment="Exit")

strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, when=crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28)), comment="Sell")
strategy.exit("Sell", trail_points=100, loss=100, comment="Exit")
```

`loss` = When price comes 100 ticks away from the trigger buy/sell in loss, then exit condition comes. So loss is fixed at 100.

`trail_points` = When price comes, 100 ticks positive from the buy/sell order, then at the closing of candle, the exit condition comes. Profit is variable at candle close, but trigger at 100.

Can these two exit strategies be given in alert condition? I am not able to convert this whole strategy in alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to keep track of your position and stop losses in variables. (isLong, isShort, stopPrice, etc etc) then update then based on your entry and exit conditions.
for the trailing stop you'll have to update it every candle *and* check if its hit on every candle.
When you have everything tracked as variables properly, then you can call alertcondition as desired.

maybe this article can help: https://marketscripters.com/pine-script-strategy-vs-study/

Comment: i was able to code the stop loss in the study.. but not able to code the trailing stop for target. 
Any idea, how can i do that, like trigger point for profit is 100 points from the buy price, but will not give exit, unless the price is down 20 points from the high ?

Comment: You'll have to write that logic yourself, keeping track of `stopPrice`, your `stopDistance` and so on. Updating them every candle as needed and checking if they've been triggered every candle.
In your case, keeping track of the high and checking when price is down 20 points from it.
For more info check out https://marketscripters.com/tradingview-pine-script-trailing-stop/